# How do I get the query results to display to the screen

Tags: reactjs

I developed a search engine that queries the input's results to the console. However I want the results to display to the screen. Don't worry to much about the names of the variables I am currently updating them now as we speak. I tried to loop over my state but that lead me to an error every time I click the input. The form displays perfectly but when I click on an input the page crashes.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Axios from "axios";



const FirstLabel = styled.label`
display:block;
margin-bottom:3rem;
      `
      const SecondLabel = styled.label`
display:block;
margin-left:1rem;
margin-bottom:3rem;
      `
      const ThridLabel = styled.label`
display:block;
margin-left:-2rem;
margin-bottom:3rem;
      `
      const FirstInput = styled.input`
padding:0.5rem;
display:block;
margin-left:28rem
margin-top:1rem;
padding-left:10rem;
padding-right:10rem;
      `
      const SecInput = styled.input`
padding:0.5rem;
display:block;
margin-left:27rem
margin-top:1rem;
padding-left:10rem;
padding-right:10rem;
      `
      const ThrInput = styled.input`
padding:0.5rem;
display:block;
margin-left:30rem
margin-top:1rem;
padding-left:10rem;
padding-right:10rem;
      `
     const FirstP = styled.p`
     margin-left:-1rem;
     `
     const SecondP = styled.p`
     margin-left:-1rem;
     `
     const ThridP = styled.p`
     margin-left:1.3rem;
     `


const Input = props => {
    console.log("props",props);
    const [user,setUser] = useState([])

    const handleChanges = event => {
        setUser({...user, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});

      };

      const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(user);


        Axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=${user.name}&status=alive`)
        .then(res => setUser(res.data.results))
      };




    return(

      <div>  
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<FirstLabel>
    <FirstP>Name:</FirstP>
    <FirstInput 
    id="title"
    name="name"
     type="text" 
     onChange = { handleChanges}
      value={user.name} ></FirstInput>
</FirstLabel>
<SecondLabel>
<SecondP>Role:</SecondP>
    <SecInput 
    type="text"
    name="role"
    id="role" 
    onChange = {handleChanges} 
    value={user.role}></SecInput>
</SecondLabel>
<ThridLabel>
<ThridP>Experience:</ThridP>
    <ThrInput 
    id="Experience"
    name="Experience"
    type="text" 
    onChange = {handleChanges} 
    value={user.Experience} ></ThrInput>
</ThridLabel>
<button>Submit!</button>
</form>
{user.map(i => <div key={i.id}>{i.name}</div>)}
     </div>

    )
}
export default Input
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting? You might want to use a different `useState` for your form and your results.

You are changing data types of your user state. It is initialized to an array but set to an object in `handleChanges`, and I'm assuming back to an array in `handleSubmit`. Don't know if that is a cause, but its not a good practice.